# .htaccess regex file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I would like some help regarding regex in .htaccess for url. I have this url I want to represent, I am pretty sure my regex code is accurate but when I load the page it gives me a 404 error. I am not sure but maybe I am missing something. Please help me out if you can.

original:

```
display-item.php?ic=70efdf2ec9b086079795c442636b55fb-17&n=Cosmetic%20For%20Women
```

ui has an md5 followed by a `-` then an `id` then `n` accepts a string with spaces

regex:

```
RewriteRule ^display/(/^[a-z0-9]{32}+\-[1-9][0-9]{0,10}$/)/(^[a-zA-Z0-9\.\s\-]+) view/display-item.php?ic=$1&n=$2
```

Comment: It may help to use an .htaccess tester: http://htaccess.mwl.be/